# PIVOT basics: Why do my aggregate return NULL?

Tags: sql, windows-server-2008, pivot

I've got a basic PIVOT-question here that probably won't cause you gurus any trouble:

Ive got this SQL that is working fine:

```
SELECT order_year, SUM(amount) AS Amount 
FROM dbo.mytable
GROUP BY order_year;
```

This returns sonething like:

```
2010 7000000
2007 8051222
2008 7099057
2009 13088790
```

Now I want to pivot the table using the same principles as described in this MSDN-article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

I tried this:

```
SELECT 'Amount' AS Total_Amount_Sorted_By_Order_Year, 
[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM
(SELECT order_year, amount 
    FROM dbo.mytable ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
SUM(amount)
FOR order_year IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])
) AS PivotTable;
```

But this returns a bunch of NULLs! :(

```
Amount NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the actual year values [2010],[2009] rather than [0],[1] etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you Barry. I misread the documentation on MSDN, and thought the [0], [1] etc labels where enumerations of the pivot-columns... (!)

Replacing them with the actual Years made the aggregations work!

```
SELECT 'Amount' AS Total_Amount_Sorted_By_Order_Year,  
[2007], [2008], [2009], [2010]
FROM 
(SELECT order_year, amount  
    FROM dbo.mytable ) AS SourceTable 
PIVOT 
( 
SUM(amount) 
FOR order_year IN ([2007], [2008], [2009], [2010]) 
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: I must have worked through 5 different examples trying this, ALL of which used [0], [1] etc... I thought this was an ordinal!